# Sort multidimentional array of objects by value

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have an xml source that brings me some data each time. I parse the xml with php's `simpleXML` and the generated array looks like the one below. My problem is that i need to sort the array ascending based on the value that carries the time.

```
Array
    (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [dict] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [key] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => channel
                                        [1] => title
                                        [2] => time
                                    )

                                [string] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => OTE SPORT 3
                                        [1] => ΕΡΓΟΤΕΛΗΣ - ΤΡΙΚΑΛΑ
                                        [2] => 20:00
                                        [3] => Ποδόσφαιρο
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [key] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => channel
                                        [1] => title
                                        [2] => time
                                    )

                                [string] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => NOVASPORTS 1
                                        [1] => ΠΛΑΤΑΝΙΑΣ - ΟΛΥΜΠΙΑΚΟΣ
                                        [2] => 19:30
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [dict] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                            (
                                [key] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => channel
                                        [1] => title
                                        [2] => time
                                    )

                                [string] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => NOVASPORTS 2
                                        [1] => ΚΟΛΟΣΣΟΣ - ΟΛΥΜΠΙΑΚΟΣ
                                        [2] => 16:00
                                        [3] => Μπάσκετ
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
    )
```

Comment: maybe `usort` ? show an attempt

Comment: Something's not clear in your question. You want to sort on time, but time is part of the deepest level, so: 1) Seems somewhat obvious you want the couple `[key]` + `[string]` be an undivisible piece which will take its rank depending on `[key][time]`, and it's right for sorting such couples _inside a `[dict]` context_; 2) But what about the upper level? If _all_ couples must be sorted in a unique series, how do you plan to define to which `[#][dict]` item they should actually belong?